# jQuery work in JSON

Tags: php, jquery

I want to send data from `index.php` to the browser through AJAX. I want to encode it in JSON and to decode it to work on it. I am using `jQuery.ajax()`. Can you point me to a tutorial?

Comment: Hmm, for your own good, googling "JSON Encode Ajax/jQuery" would get you 100 more answers at a 10th of the time.

Comment: **Thanks phil** for quick reply. but i will appreciate if you can send me a good artical for me.. i google and search it but not understandable result :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your ajax call looks something like this

```
$.ajax({
   ....
   .....
   dataType: 'json', // required
   success: function(data) { // data variable is where your json is stored
       console.log(data); // view entire json object in firebug or other console
       alert(data.name); // access value of array key called name 
   }

});
```

I recommend placing a `console.log` call in the success function to see what the json object looks like.

Comment: thanx trevor. i has a little question is here . what is in my data veriable that i can send to my index.php page.. i have not a json result to send it to my index.php page ?

Comment: The JSON variable should contain whatever array you acquired from your PHP script. The script your ajax data should be pulling from should end with `echo json_encode($yourArray);`

Answer (score 2):

In your index.php put this jquery code

```
$.post("data_provider.php",{'your_param': param_value},
     function(data){

     var jsonObj = JSON.parse(data);

      //use your data here 
     jsonObj.id;
     jsonObj.name; 

});
```

In your data_provider.php, get your data from DB for example and encode them using json_encode function. 
For example :

```
$your_data = array('id' => $id, 'name' => $name );

echo json_encode ($your_data);
```

In ajax call you can use get or post according to your needs.